# Getting Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < django-jquery-fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, file-upload

I am trying to integrate django-jquery-fileupload

https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload

But I get "Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "when i click on "start" upload button.

I don't get what is creating the error.

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/nhZHnEaV

Comment: Check the syntax on the line referenced in the traceback, otherwise post the full traceback.

Comment: You've got far too much code. Cut it down to the smallest example that shows the problem, then post it *here* - along with the actual traceback showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Chrome Debugger or one of its ilk and check what happened when your scripts were loaded. That sometimes happens when a template gets rendered and sent in place of some resource and is interpreted as js.

Comment: unable to find any thing with the debugger

Answer (score 0):

This error comes in jquery-template syntax. Replace old jquery-template js with latest one.

Comment: Ya, I changed the file tmpl.min.js , now the delete option is working but I still get the error "Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Answer (score -1):

Please check main.js and check if the url that is set in the beginning matches the url where you have the server uploader.